# Qt android : How can I use a java file without registering it as the main activity in the manifest?

Tags: android, qt, java-native-interface, qtquick2, qtandroidextras

I can use JNI to issue a notification using a java file. The only way I can do that is by replacing the activity line in the manifest like so:
From:

```
<activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" >
```

To the path for the java file:

```
<activity android:name="org.qtproject.example.notification.NotificationClient" >
```

or else the notifications won't show up!

What if I want to Use more than one Java file to do other stuff using JNI?
How can I add more than one activity in the manifest?

This is my NotificationClient.java:

```
package org.qtproject.example.notification;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity;

public class NotificationClient extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    private static Notification.Builder m_builder;
    private static NotificationClient m_instance;
    private static PendingIntent contentIntent;
    private static Intent intent;

    public NotificationClient()
    {
        m_instance = this;

    }

    public  static void notify(String s)
    {
        if (m_notificationManager == null) {
            m_notificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            m_builder = new Notification.Builder(m_instance);
            m_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

            m_builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            m_builder.setContentTitle("A message from Qt!");
        }

    intent = new Intent(m_instance, NotificationClient.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(m_instance, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

m_builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

       m_builder.setContentText(s);
       m_notificationManager.notify(1, m_builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does NotificationClient extends Activity ?

Comment: _"How can I add more than one activity in the manifest?"_ By adding an `<activity>` tag for each activity. It's not clear to me exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @Michael If i add an extra <activity> tag for the notificationClient java class, the notifications don't show up. So, i think the java class is not seen.
But, if I change the main activity as i described above, the notifications work, so the java file is seen.

Comment: You should add some code that shows how you're actually trying to show the notifications, because so far you haven't given us a whole lot of info.

Comment: @j2ko yes, it extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity

Comment: @Michael
I published my NotificationClient.java that issues the notifications.

Comment: @j2ko
I published my NotificationClient.java that issues the notifications.

Comment: `notify` is using the static field `m_instance` that isn't set until at least one `NotificationClient` has been created (and then changes whenever a new `NotificationClient` is created). This seems like a pretty odd (and possibly buggy) design to me. Why can't `notify` receive the necessary `Context` as an argument?

Comment: @Mena are you following this example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html ?

Comment: What I can say, the way they provide example is totally bad... I don't even know from where to start... The reason why you running into issue is because activity should be started in order to initialize static variable and this simply will not happen automatically unless it's the main activity

Comment: @j2ko Yes, I am following that example. That's very interesting! But, now how can I initialize the static variable manually?

Comment: @j2ko Can u plz take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365978/qt-android-qt-notification-example-how-to-use-it-without-making-it-the-main-a

Comment: @Michael Well, i don't know why notify does not receive the necessary Context as an argument. That was the example provided by Qt for android notifications. Can you please explain how I can improve it as you suggested above? Also, does it have to extend Activity?